# UIBarButtonItem crashes when UINavigationItem.prompt exists

Tags: ios

My app started crashing on iOS 11 devices when the user presses any button in any navigation bar, but only when the navigation item is displaying the prompt. After I set prompt to nil and the prompt disappears, the buttons work fine. It works fine with iOS 10.2 with and without the prompt.

The error is:

```
-[_UIBackButtonContainerView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a608460
```

The prompt is displayed with:

```
for (UINavigationItem *item in self.navigationController.navigationBar.items) {
        item.prompt = NSLocalizedString(@"message.reconnecting", @"short message that indicates wireless signal is attempting to reconnect");
    }
```

The prompt is hidden with:

```
for (UINavigationItem *item in self.navigationController.navigationBar.items) {
    item.prompt = nil;
}
```

In this image, the back button and Advanced button both cause the crash
[image: navigation bar]

I have run this in iOS 11 with the prompt definition commented out and all the other code of the project as is and it does not crash.

Any ideas if iOS 11 API changes took effect regarding nav bars and its items, I can't find any.

Comment: If you can reproduce this will a simple test app, submit a bug report to Apple along with your little test app.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! In the process of trying to reproduce in a simple test app, I discovered my coding error. I had assigned a backBarButtonItem and a leftBarButtonItem on the first ViewController embedded in the NavigationController..